# What's a simple workaround for this bug in PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser 1.5?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Can anyone suggest a simple code (not data) workaround for this bug in PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser 1.5?

```
$html = str_get_html('<html><body><table><tr><td><td><tr><td><td></body></html>');
$r=$html->find('tr',0);
echo count($r->find('td')); // Expected: 2 ; Observed: 4
[code using $r]
```

EDIT: This issue occurs even with added

```
</table>
```

(^ workaround for this site's misinterpretation of that string inline).

EDIT: I find advanced html dom fixes this problem but is not a compatible replacement. See incomatible [How to workaround PHP advanced html dom's conversion of entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277100/how-to-workaround-php-advanced-html-doms-conversion-of-entities)

Comment: Are you sure this is a bug in parser? This is not valid HTML code.

Comment: [cen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1084605/cen) is right. You are missing the closing table tag. Should be `$html = str_get_html('<html><body><table><tr><td><td><tr><td><td></table></body></html>');`. Not to mention the tbody tag... In my opinion should be something like this: `$html = str_get_html('<html><body><table><tbody><tr><td><td><tr><td><td></tbody></table></body></html>');`

Comment: "You are missing the closing table tag". Point taken, but does adding it avoid the problem for you? Not for me. "Not to mention the tbody tag..." No tbody tag is required.

Comment: "In my opinion should be something like this" That gives the same fail here.

Comment: `<tr>` tag is not closed...

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Damn! I totally overlooked those!

Comment: @ChrisJJ Nobody's perfect. :) Sorry for I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: @Tomasz "<tr> tag is not closed.." The <tr> element is closed implicitly.  The <tr> end tag is optional https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags .

Answer (score 1):

The simplest workaround is to switch to [this library](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom) which fixes this issue and lots of other ones.

Comment: Thanks. Looks great... except for the lack of documentation.

Comment: Yeah, nobody likes to do documentation. Feel free to contribute :)

Comment: Hmm. It says it is a drop-in replacement. When I drop it in, I get "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function str_get_html()"

Comment: You're doing something wrong then. Maybe you forgot to `include` it?

Comment: Sorry - it was a faulty download. The change does fix this problem - thanks - but I find the library is not a compatible replacement. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277100/how-to-workaround-php-advanced-html-doms-conversion-of-entities