# How to workaround PHP advanced html dom's conversion of entities?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

How can I workaround advanced_html_dom.php str_get_html's conversion of HTML entities, short of applying htmlentities() on every element content?

Despite

http://archive.is/YWKYp#selection-971.0-979.95

> The goal of this project is to be a DOM-based drop-in replacement for
>   PHP's simple html dom library.
>
> ... If you use file/str_get_html then you don't need to change
>   anything.

I find on

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$set = str_get_html('<html><title>&nbsp;</title></html>');
echo ($set->find('title',0)->innertext)."\n";  // Expected: &nbsp;  Observed: &nbsp;
```

changing to advanced HTML DOM gives an incompatible result:

```
include 'advanced_html_dom.php';
$set = str_get_html('<html><title>&nbsp;</title></html>');
echo ($set->find('title',0)->innertext)."\n";    // Expected: &nbsp;  Observed: -á
```

This issue is not confined to spaces.

```
$set = str_get_html('<html><body>&bull;</body></html>'); 
echo $set->find('body',0)->innertext; // Expected $bull; Observed ÔÇó
```

Comment: That's interesting, but it's not what I get. Maybe it's an encoding issue? You should be reporting bugs on github, not here.

Comment: "You should be reporting bugs on github, not here." That's why I am not reporting the bug here :) I'm asking for a workaround.

Comment: The best workaround is probably to submit an issue on github.

Comment: "That's interesting, but it's not what I get." Thanks. What do you get? "Maybe it's an encoding issue?" I see no encoding. The HTML source is an ASCII string.

Comment: I get a space. Can you tell me about your environment? Let's move the discussion to github, yes?

Comment: "I get a space." Well since there's no space in the HTML, that sure sounds like a bug "Can you tell me about your environment?" http://i.imgur.com/gksn5mq.png

Comment: converting the `&nbsp;` is intentional.

Comment: "converting the &nbsp; is intentional" Evidently not, given "If you use file/str_get_html then you don't need to change anything."

Comment: Read the next paragraph. If you need `&nbsp;`'s then you should switch back to simple.

Comment: "Read the next paragraph" It says "What's Different - Mostly just formatting (spaces) in the html." ... fro some value of Mostly. I added incompatibility on non-space to the Q.

Comment: *sigh* - `&nbsp;` is a space.

Comment: "sigh - &nbsp; is a space." What I said was "I added incompatibility on **non-space** to the Q"

Comment: It's still not an issue. The text value of that html entity is returned and that is desired behaviour.

Comment: it is not the desired behaviour of anyone relying on advanced_html_dom's "If you use file/str_get_html then you don't need to change anything."https://archive.is/QtSuj#selection-933.34-933.100 because it can break code.

Comment: I've posted this as an issue on github. https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom/issues/8

Answer (score 0):

You can check my own package [PHPHTMLQuery](http://abdelilahlbardi.github.io/phphtmlquery/), it helps you to use PHP to select HTML element using most of CSS3 selectors.

> the package works with external links and internal html files too.

**Installation**

Open your terminal and browse into your project root folder and run

```
composer require "abdelilahlbardi/phphtmlquery":"@dev"
```

**Documentation**

For more informations, please visit the package link: [PHPHTMLQuery](https://github.com/AbdelilahLbardi/phphtmlquery)

Comment: links are dead!